# Adobe Air Application Cannot Install on IPAD2

Tags: ios, iphone, air

I am trying to install my adobe air app to my IPAD 2 (IOS 7.1) through itune sysnc, but it just showing "installing" .. but nothing happends, but the same app successfully installs on my IPOD touch (IOS 7.1). Anybody knows what is the issue here?Help is highly appreciable.

Thanks,

Comment: Stackoverflow is a site for programming help. Because you are only downloading an app, it is not the type of question that should be asked on this site. Maybe http://apple.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask?

Comment: This could well be a programming issue, if you regard publish settings as part of programming.

Answer (score 0):

What version of the air sdk are you using? I know that versions prior to 4 or 13 beta may have issues on ios7

Comment: Exception to this. I've had no problem publishing to iOS 7 with earlier versions of AIR.

Comment: Yes I did say "may". It doesn't happen all the time but it still happens. I could not upload an app on application loader until I switched to air 4. Also before overlaying air, the app would install on the 4s but not on the iphone 5.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a provisioning profile problem? Re-publish the app, double-checking that the app-ID matches the ID that you built into the provisioning profile. If you're not using an ad- hoc profile, make sure that you install the provisioning profile on your iPad before you install and try to run the app.